# Dúvida com extração de mês e ano em data PostgreSql

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

Estou usando um comando select onde pego o mes e o ano da data da seguinte forma:

`extract(year from D.dt_ficha) + extract(month from D.dt_ficha)`

Só que ao invés de aparecer assim: `201711` novembro de 2017, ele está somando 2017 + 11 `2028`.

Como corrigir?

Comment: tente || no lugar do +

Comment: ERRO:  operador não existe: double precision || double precision

Comment: cast(extract(year from D.dt_ficha) as text) || cast(extract(month from D.dt_ficha) as text)  não testei pois não tenho postgresql

Comment: @Motta testei assim, mas quando o mês é menor que 10, ele não mostra o zero. mas já consegui resolver, postei a resposta embaixo. Abraço

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi assim:

```
to_char(D.dt_ficha, 'YYYYMM') as data,
```

Answer (score 3):

Tente assim:

```
SELECT  extract(year from D.dt_ficha) || '' || extract(month from D.dt_ficha)
    from D
```

Onde `D` seria sua tabela;
Para mim funcionou corretamente.

Answer (score 0):

Você também pode utilizar a função date_trunc:

```
date_trunc('month', TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:40')
```

que obterá como resultado:

```
2001-02-01 00:00:00
```

Answer (score -1):

Tente utilizar "||"

```
extract(year from D.dt_ficha) || extract(month from D.dt_ficha)
```